# What is the significance of AlertDialog.Builder class?

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog, builder

In Android every dialog is shown using `Builder` for that dialog class. The `Builder` is the static inner class in these classes. So why the Builder is given the control to build the dialog? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is just a helper class which allows you to call methods in a chain and set positive/negative buttons easily. For example:

**AlertDialog.Builder**

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
  .setTitle("this is title")
  .setMessage("this is message")
  .setCancelable(false)
  .setPositiveButton("OK", null);
  alert.show();
```

**AlertDialog**

```
AlertDialog alert2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
alert2.setTitle("this is title");
alert2.setMessage("");
alert2.setCancelable(false);
alert2.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK", new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // null 
    }
});
alert2.show();
```

So now you may see the difference in ease of creating same thing with two different ways.

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree with [waqaslam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/966550/waqaslam), but at the same time, AlertDialog gives you more way of customizing your dialog. Like you can apply animation in AlertDialog easily by using

```
// Create an enter animation(name = enter_anim)
<translate android:fromXDelta="-100%p"
    android:fromYDelta="0%"
    android:duration="1000">

</translate>

//Create an exit animation(name = exit_anim)
<translate
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromXDelta="0%"
    android:toXDelta="100%p">

</translate>

//Then combine the enter and exit animation by creating a style
<style name="DialogSlide">
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/enter_anim</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/exit_anim</item>
</style>

//Now creating an AlertDialog
AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
    dialog.setTitle("Alert Dialog");
    dialog.setMessage("Hello! This is an alert dialog");
    dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations=R.style.DialogSlide;
    dialog.show();
```

//This line attaches animation to your Dialog, which you will not find in AlertDialog.Builder class

```
dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations=R.style.DialogSlide;
```

So, by this way you can create any type of animation and attach to the AlertDialog by creating style.
But I think you can rarely achieve this by using AlertDialog.Builder class.
And hence you can give better user experience to the user by using animations.